# Statistics behind gravitational waves discovery

Tags: time-series, astronomy

The recent gravitational waves result is a stunning feat for both physics and engineering. I suspect there may be much to admire on the statistics side as well. For example, [the original paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) states:

> Events are assigned a detection-statistic value that ranks their
>   likelihood of being a gravitational-wave signal. The significance of a
>   candidate event is determined by the search background—the rate at
>   which detector noise produces events with a detection-statistic value
>   equal to or higher than the candidate event. Estimating this
>   background is challenging for two reasons: the detector noise is
>   nonstationary and non-Gaussian, so its properties must be empirically
>   determined; and it is not possible to shield the detector from
>   gravitational waves to directly measure a signal-free background. The
>   specific procedure used to estimate the background is slightly
>   different for the two searches, but both use a time-shift technique:
>   the time stamps of one detector’s data are artificially shifted by an
>   offset that is large compared to the intersite propagation time, and a
>   new set of events is produced based on this time-shifted data set. For
>   instrumental noise that is uncorrelated between detectors this is an
>   effective way to estimate the background. In this process a
>   gravitational wave signal in one detector may coincide with
>   time-shifted noise transients in the other detector, thereby
>   contributing to the background estimate.

I'm seeking a more detailed description of this process geared toward a general statistics audience rather than toward a physics or highly specialized statistics audience.

I understand this is a squishy question, and if it's not appropriate for CV in its current form, I would appreciate suggestions for improving it.

Comment: As mentioned on [Andrew Gelman blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2016/02/15/if-karl-popper-edited-the-new-york-times/), they used [STAN and MCMC](https://dcc.ligo.org/P1500217/public).